# Invalid argument Supplied for foreach() Axios Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have a Vue.js form and I submit the form using Axios. I'm able to save the data to my database. However, when I want to save my dynamically added input fields I get this error message...

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach

The problem is that it's not an array but it should be. As you can see, I would like to send the teams[] array from the Vue component to the Laravel backend with Axios. When i console.log() teams [object object], [object object].

**app.js**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#regapp',

    data: {
        username: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        password_confirmation: '',
        teams: [
            {
                name: '',
                role: '',
                linkedin: '',
                profileimg: ''
            }
        ],
        methods: {
            onSubmit() {
                axios.defaults.headers.common["X-CSRF-TOKEN"] = document
                    .querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
                    .getAttribute("content");
                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('username', this.username);
                formData.append('email', this.email);
                formData.append('password', this.password);
                formData.append('password_confirmation', this.password_confirmation);
                formData.append('teams', this.teams);

                axios.post('register', formData)
                    .then(response => alert('Success'))
                    .catch(error => this.errors.record(error.response.data.errors));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Controller.php**

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->name = $data['username'];
    $user->email = $data['email'];
    $user->password = Hash::make($data['password']);
    $user->save();

    // Here I try to loop trough teams and save each of them names into db.
    if ($data['teams'][0] != NULL) {
        $format = (array)$data;
        foreach ($format['teams'] as $teams) { // The error is here
            $team = new Team();
            $team->user_id = $user->id;
            $team->tmembername = $teams->name;
            $team->save();
        }
    }

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: can you dump `$format['teams']` and show us the outpu ?because it's not array or object so foreach can't iterate it in loop

Comment: This is the dd
["teams"]=>
  string(31) "[object Object],[object Object]"
It is seams like axios not able to send through object it converts it to string but i dont know why

Comment: can you define content type  as application/json . I know it's application/json manually but just in case,

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Hassan for the help.
The problem was that this.teams is an array of objects - it just tries to convert the Object to a String, hence getting [object Object].
So i can't do this:

```
formData.append('teams', this.teams);
```

I had to:

```
var teammemb = JSON.stringify(this.teams);
```

Then:

```
formData.append('teams', teammemb);
```

On my RegisterController.php

```
 $csapat = (json_decode($data['teams']));

if (is_array($csapat) || is_object($csapat)) {
 // in this contition, foreach gonna work only array or object exist


  foreach ($csapat as $teams) {
   $team = new Team();
   $team->ico_id = $ico->id;
   $team->tmembername = $teams->name;
   $team->save();
  }
}
```

It works now.